# How to get Hashmap values that are inside Arraylist

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I have data that structured like this (See the code).

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetUsers(String Query) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap();
            user.put("hotelid", rs.getString(COLUMN_HotelID));
            user.put("countery", rs.getString(COLUMN_Countery));
            user.put("city", rs.getString(COLUMN_CITY));
            user.put("hotelname", rs.getString(COLUMN_HOTELNAME));
            user.put("startdate", rs.getString(COLUMN_STARTDATE));
            user.put("enddate", rs.getString(COLUMN_ENDDATE));
            userList.add(user);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQLiteJDBC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
    }
    return userList;
}
```

Every time I iterate over the arraylist I get values like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(userList.get(i));
}
```

`{enddate=6/6/2019, 
city=karak, 
hotelid=11, 
startdate=4/22/2019, 
countery=jordan, 
hotelname=Dalallah}`

I want to print the values in a different way like selecting the value that I want to print.

Comment: If you want to model a user in Java, using a `HashMap` to store lose key value pairs will not be the *object oriented way*... Create a class `User` that holds the user values...

Comment: Yes, its not OOP oriented , but its worked nicely !!

Comment: Your decision... If it works as desired, then fine ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get an element from the list, you can execute any method on it, e.g., `Map#get`. So, e.g., if you want to print all the hotel names:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(userList.get(i).get("hotelname");
     // Here --------------------------^
}
```